# PCB components/ creation

Tags: pcb-design, cad, terminal-block

I am tasked with the creation of a PCB that is quite simple. It is only a simple route from a 26 pin MDR to a 2 pin terminal block. I am stuck though.

I am using Fusion 360 and I have a few questions.

What do I need to specify to get the board created? Does each component need a callout somehow?

How would I specify this device in particular?

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/3m/10126-52B2PC/1091735

I think if I can get the .lib file that would help. Is there another way? Am I totally off base here?

The second component is a terminal block. How would I get this guy on there?
https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-us/products/pcb-terminal-block-lpta-16-2-100-zb-1333817

Comment: Sounds to me like you should start by reading/watching a basic tutorial on PCB design in F360. I'm sure there are loads out there.

Comment: I have, so the problem is I cant find a .lbr file to upload. How do I get a part from phoenix contact in there? If a .lbr file is not provided, Do I need to create a new  file and after I do so, what is the PCB creator expecting? Do I need a callout for the part? Can I link it back to the step file somehow?

Comment: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fusion-360-electronics/step-files-into-electronic-library-3d-packages/m-p/9695088#M2487 Found this. I need to create the package from footprint option. I guess I have to create the footprint myself. Or can I get footprint from step file?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you cannot find a schematic symbol or a footprint in your libraries, you'll have to create them yourself. There is however nowadays a huge number of parts available on http://snapeda.com

Comment: Okay, I have made everything but the 3D model, I'll put it on snapeda.com when finished, crazy that they can engineer all of this stuff and sell it without providing the model and footprint/ symbol.